# Sending uia command "target.deactivateAppForDuration()" in calabash-ios consolre returns error message

Tags: ios, calabash-ios, uia

I am creating some iOS *automation tests*. When I call send_uia_command

```
:command => "target.deactivateAppForDuration(5)"
```

in calabash-ios console, the app goes to background, after duration background app screen is opened and I get the following error:

```
  RuntimeError: uia action failed because: Input: target.deactivateAppForDuration(5)
 . Error: VerboseError: -[UIAElementNil _prepareForAction:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17676700  deactivateAppForDuration@[native code]
   eval code
   eval@[native code]
```

What could be the issue?

Update: This error is returned only on iOS 9.

iOS 8.4.1 works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the [Calabash iOS 0.16.3 release notes.](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/blob/develop/changelog/0.16.3.md)

The short answer is that UIAutomation deactivateAppForDuration is broken on iOS 9.

There is a radar and we are [tracking this issue here](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/issues/836).

When reporting problems with Calabash, please follow this [guide](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki#reporting-problems).